# Performing set-like operations on XML

Tags: c#, .net, xml, difference, set-operations

Is there a mechanism in C#/.NET to perform set-like operations on complex XML structures in a general manner?

For instance, suppose i have the following XML structure A:

```
<a:rPr lang="en-US" sz="1500" b="1" i="1">                            
<a:effectLst>
    <a:glow rad="139700">
        <a:schemeClr val="accent4">
            <a:satMod val="175000"/>
            <a:alpha val="40000"/>
        </a:schemeClr>
    </a:glow>
    <a:innerShdw blurRad="63500" dist="50800" dir="18900000">
        <a:prstClr val="black">
            <a:alpha val="50000"/>
        </a:prstClr>
    </a:innerShdw>
    <a:reflection blurRad="6350" stA="60000" endA="900" endPos="58000" dir="5400000" sy="-100000" algn="bl" rotWithShape="0"/>
</a:effectLst>    
</a:rPr>
```

And a second XML structure B:

```
<a:rPr lang="en-US" sz="1500" b="1" i="1">                            
<a:effectLst>
    <a:innerShdw blurRad="63500" dist="50800" dir="18900000">
        <a:prstClr val="black">
            <a:alpha val="50000"/>
        </a:prstClr>
    </a:innerShdw>
    <a:reflection blurRad="6350" stA="60000" endA="900" endPos="58000" dir="5400000" sy="-100000" algn="bl" rotWithShape="0"/>
</a:effectLst>    
</a:rPr>
```

I'd like to be able to perform operations such as union, intersection or difference. As an example, i expect from A - B the following result:

```
<a:rPr lang="en-US" sz="1500" b="1" i="1">                            
<a:effectLst>        
    <a:glow rad="139700">
        <a:schemeClr val="accent4">
            <a:satMod val="175000"/>
            <a:alpha val="40000"/>
        </a:schemeClr>
    </a:glow>
</a:effectLst>    
</a:rPr>
```

Is there such a mechanism already available in the .NET framework or 3rd party libraries or would i have to implement it from scratch?

Comment: Directly in xml? No. You can deserialize xml into corresponding type and add support for operations you want, then serialize result to xml.

Comment: LINQ to XML would be suitable ? look here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt693161.aspx